# Optimization in scipy for a matrix

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to find the optimize matrix with binary entries (0,1) so that my objective function get maximized.

My X input is a 2-dimensional matrix with 0 and 1 entries.

My objective function is like this:

```
def objective(x):
    w=[[2,3],[4,6],[1,0],[2,8]]
    return -1* (x[0][0]*w[0][0]+x[0][1]*w[0][1]+x[1][0]*w[1][0]+x[1][1]*w[1][1])
```

And here is my initial X:

```
x0=[[1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,0]]
```

Here I define the boundaries for X:

```
b=(0,1)
bnds=((b,b),(b,b))
```

And finally the maximization problem

```
sol=minimize(objective2,x0,method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds)
```

But I have two problems:

First: The bnds has different dimension than my X and I get an error for that.
Second, when I run the minimize function I get and error that says invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: I think your `x0` has to be 1d.  I answered a recent question along that line.

Comment: @hpaulj So you mean there is no way that it could be 2-D ?

Comment: That's not a serious constraint, since you can ravel and reshape it in your function as needed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541910/problems-with-scipy-optimize-using-matrix-as-input-bounds-constraints

Comment: Thanks but even that question has not been answered correctly yet

Comment: Are you trying to use this `scipy` function without first learning basics of `numpy`?

Comment: I am not trying to learn scipy. I have something in mind to do and for doing that I found out that I should use scipy. So the task is not to learn scipy or numpy. My goal is to implement my idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the reshaping that I had in mind

```
In [293]: objective(x0)
Out[293]: -6
In [294]: def foo(x):
   .....:     return objective(x.reshape(-1,2))
   .....: 
In [295]: foo(np.array(x0).ravel())
Out[295]: -6
In [296]: from scipy.optimize import minimize
In [297]: minimize(foo, x0, method='SLSQP')
Out[297]: 
     fun: -801353716.84727359
     jac: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 130
     nit: 13
    njev: 13
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([  2.46570281e+07,   3.69855528e+07,   4.93140795e+07,
         7.39711140e+07,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00])
```

I have't incorporated the bounds yet

```
In [290]: np.array(bnds).shape
Out[290]: (2, 2, 2)
```

They have to be compatible with the flattened `x0`

```
In [298]: np.array(x0).ravel()
Out[298]: array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

For example, this constrains all values between 0 and 1

```
In [301]: bnds=np.array((np.zeros(8),np.ones(8))).T
In [302]: bnds
Out[302]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
In [303]: minimize(foo, x0, method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds)
Out[303]: 
     fun: -14.999999999999773
     jac: array([-2., -3., -4., -6.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 20
     nit: 2
    njev: 2
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.])
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, but your answer is not quite readable. I appreciate if you could make it a little clearer and organized.

Comment: Most of my answer is copied from an actual Ipython interactive session.